# Kivy: my application isn't hardware accelerated

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

At the moment I'm building a Kivy application to control custom hardware that opens and closes lockers. To accomplish this, I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ along with a custom 10" touchscreen which is connected to my raspberry. The OS I'm using is Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit). I've followed all the steps to install Kivy detailed in [Installing Kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip) and thus installed the pre-compiled wheel. Everything works perfectly, but it seems I cant get my application hardware accelerated.

When I try to run my App I see the following:

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.1 Mesa 20.3.5'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Mesa/X.org'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 128 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.40'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
```

According to [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-rpi.html#install-source-rpi) page it means that my application is not hardware accelerated.
So following the steps detailed there I used `groups <user>` to check if my user is in the render group, which it is:

`<user>: <user> adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input render netdev spi i2c gpio lpadmin docker`

I've tried several combinations by setting the KIVY_GL_BACKEND and KIVY_WINDOW, but nothing works. At the moment I'm using the following function to start my application (haven't set my environment variables yet, but will do so in the future):

```
def initialize(self):
    if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
        os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')
        os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'sdl2'
        os.environ['KIVY_WINDOW'] = 'sdl2'
```

And use the following lines to make my application maximized:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
```

How can I make it so my application is hardware accelerated?

Update 1:

Reinstalled a 32-bit version of the raspberry pi os (with desktop).
I've tried installing the required libraries: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip build-essential git python3 python3-dev ffmpeg libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev zlib1g-dev`. I've then ran `python -m pip install "kivy[base]" kivy_examples --no-binary kivy` to build kivy from source. I then removed SDL2 using `sudo apt-get -y remove libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev` and followed the instructions to install `SDL2, SDL2_image, SDL2_mixer, SDL2_ttf` and used the command `sudo ldconfig -v`  to update the dynamic library cache, checked the groups again and see my user is in the render group, and then ran a simple kivy app:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

which, in turn presented me again with:

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.1 Mesa 20.3.5'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Mesa/X.org'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 128 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.40'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
```

Update 2:

1. Went into `sudo raspi-config`
2. Went into '1 System Options     Configure system settings'
3. Choose the option 'S5 Boot / Auto Login Select boot into desktop or to command line'
4. Choose the option 'B2 Console Autologin Text console, automatically logged in as '' user'.
5. Rebooted into the headless console and re-ran the small test script from Update 1.
6. I got greeted by the following:

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 Mesa 20.3.5'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'VC4 V3D 2.1'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
```

7. Profit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to compile SDL2 from source if you want to make a kivy app hardware accelerated on a console and not on a desktop environment.
[Follow this instruction](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-rpi.html#raspberry-pi-4-headless-installation-on-raspbian-buster)

Comment: I'm gonna try your suggestion by installing raspi OS lite and using the installation instructions on the kivy website